# UISwitch re-positioning at the end of the cell when orientation changes

Tags: iphone

I have a problem with UISwitch repositioning on device rotation. the switch is part of a table view and when the orientation changes, I am explicitly setting the switch frame in the didChangeInterfaceRotation() method. It works fine but the transition 
is not smooth and there is a lag in the tableview resizing and the switch frame setting that I see on the simulator. That makes it look a bit weird. Can you tell me a way by which I can do this more smoothly.

Comment: Are you adding it as an accessory view of your cell?

Comment: If you want to mimic the Settings app you should add it as an accessory view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments do it the following way. I do it also like this. Because if you add the switch as a accessoryView, the tableviewcell will automatically resize the textlabel. So you don't have to worry about that anyway.

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
mySwitch.on = YES; //Or no :-D

//If necessary add a target with a action
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(anAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 

cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;
[mySwitch release];
```

I hope my answer helped you out. This is the easiest way to add a switch to a cell.

Sandro Meier